# Cannot find a module after run npm install (Docker)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize a node-app, but for some reason when I start the app using:

docker-compose -f docker-compose -f docker-compose.override.yml

I'm getting a error ** Error: Cannot find module 'connect-flash' *** but the module is defined in package.json.

Apparently only a limited number of modules was installed with npm install

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

My files:

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:14

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

ENV HOME=/home/node/

USER node

WORKDIR $HOME/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.7.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mathjs": "^8.0.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.15",
    "mongoose-float": "^1.0.4",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.11",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pug": "^3.0.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.14.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "snyk": "^1.431.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nodejs_coin_container:
    image: nodejs
    container_name: coin_nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - coin-network
  mongodb_coin_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: coin_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - coin-network
  webserver_coin:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver_coin
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - nodejs_coin_container    
    networks:
      - coin-network    
  certbot_coin:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot_coin
    depends_on:
      - webserver_coin
networks:
  coin-network:
    driver: bridge
```

docker-compose-override.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nodejs_coin_container:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
      MONGO_USERNAME: "${MONGO_USERNAME}"
      MONGO_PASSWORD: "${MONGO_PASSWORD}"
      MONGO_HOSTNAME: mongodb_coin_container
      MONGO_PORT: "${MONGO_PORT}"
      MONGO_DB: "${MONGO_DB}"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - node_modules_coin:/home/node/app/node_modules
    command: node index.js --NODE_ENV=development
  webserver_coin:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web_root_coin:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nodejs_coin_container    
    networks:
      - coin-network 
  mongodb_coin_container:
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "${MONGO_USERNAME}"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MONGO_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - mongodb_coin_data_container:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodb_coin_data_container:
  node_modules_coin:
  web_root_coin:
```

Comment: Add node_modules to your .dockerignore file; it may be overwritten when you are copying project files.

Comment: The `volumes:` are telling Docker to use the old copy of the `node_modules` tree in the `node_modules_coin` named volume in precedence to the updated copy in the image.  I'd recommend deleting this `volumes:` block entirely to use the code built into the image.

Comment: @AbdullahS.Al-Hallak I forgot that, if I had added node_modules in .dockerignore

Answer (score 0):

I seriously don't know why this occures, i have faced similar issues with docker and typescript, whereby the app would run all npm install but not spin up, due to missing deps, whereas the app functions well with docker-compose on local system. But once puhed to AWS it fails blatantly. The solution i found was to

> install nodejs, and the whole project dependencies on the AWS EC2

instance first, and brefore running `docker-compose up --build` command to build.

Answer (score -1):

drop package-lock.json and node_modules

then you can run npm install